# React: Pass parameters using React-Router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

App.js where all my Routes are declared:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/">
          <Route index element={<Homepage />} />
          <Route path="settings" element={<Settings />} />
          <Route path="report/:runId" element={<TestReport />} />
          <Route path="report/:runId/:specFileName" element={<SpecFile />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here I have the Link to (in my current case) /report/2/Login where I want to pass some parameters:

```
   <TableCell>
      <Link
         to={`/report/${this.props.runId}/${specFile.name}`}
         state={{ testcases: this.props.testcases }}
      >
         {specFile.name}
      </Link>
   </TableCell>
```

Here I want to access my parameters:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function SpecFile() {
   const location = useLocation();
   const { from } = location.specFile.name;
   console.log(from); // Should print "Login" instead gives Error Message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
}
```

Comment: React router is very well documented. You just need to read it: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-params (or follow the tutorial which should also teach you this: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial)

Comment: these links are broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`location.specFile.name;` is invalid and breaks because the `location` object doesn't have any `specFile` property.

[Location](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#location)

> ```
> interface Location {
>   pathname: string;
>   search: string;
>   hash: string;
>   state: unknown;
>   key: string;
> }
> ```

Access the passed route state on `location.state`, specifically on `location.state?.testcases`.

For the given route `<Route path="report/:runId/:specFileName" element={<SpecFile />} />` the `SpecFile` component should use the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-params) hook to access the route path params `runId` and `specFileName`.

Example:

```
import { useLocation, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function SpecFile() {
  const { id, specFileName } = useParams();

  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { testcases } = state || {};

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ id, specFileName, testcases });
  }, [id, specFileName, testcases]);
  
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a hook in react-router-6 for this.

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and then use it like:

```
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
```

Comment: how can I then get the passed spec file name?